# How can I convert formatted string to int (if I know format) in C#?

Tags: c#, int, string.format

I have formatted string, for example `123 456 000$` and I know format of this string `{0:### ### ##0}$`. I'd like to get `int value = 123456000;` from this string in C# with using known format.

How I can do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469260/how-to-get-number-from-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: Do you really want to lose one of the `0` from the end of the numeric string or is that just a typo? ie the original string ends with three zeros but your int ends with only two...

Comment: I don't wont, it's just typo. But thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mytext = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(mytext.Name, "[^.0-9]", "");
```

or something approximately like that get's rid of the pesky non-numbers

and then delete the first few characters 1,2,3... and last few length, length -1, length -3...

unless I'm missing something?

Oh yeah, and Convert.Toint32(mytext)

Answer (score 2):

```
int.Parse("123 456 000$", NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol |
                          NumberStyles.Number);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c09yxbyt.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have to construct a similar `NumberFormatInfo` to parse the string value.`$` for the currency symbol used in the text and in your case the thousand group seperator is `space` instead of `,` so a custom number format info should help you parse it.

```
string val = "123 456 000$";
NumberFormatInfo numinf = new NumberFormatInfo();
numinf.CurrencySymbol = "$";
numinf.CurrencyGroupSeparator = " ";
numinf.NumberGroupSeparator = " "; // you have space instead of comma as the seperator
int requiredval = int.Parse(val,NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.AllowThousands,  numinf);
```

This should help you get the value

Answer (score 0):

I would make it easy way:

```
String formattedString = "12345500$";
            formattedString.Remove(formattedString.Length - 1);
            int value = int.Parse(formattedString);
```

Comment: I think for this to be a valid answer you'd have to explain how you got to your formatted string from the actual formatted string the OP has. If a question says "this is what I'm starting with" then you can't just say "here is an answer starting with something much simpler"...

Comment: The string value has to assigned back when you have the `Remove` part else it does nothing with the contents of the string